# How to add a Fragment ID or Fragment tag for a fragment in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I have Tabs + ViewPager in my Android app.

From the main activity, I want to send some data to these fragments. How do I get these fragments in the first place? I suppose I need to use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.--)`

How do I set the ID or the Tag in the first place?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve them on `onPageChanged` of `ViewPager` i.e. when they are slided?